# I pushed a commit on a remote branch using a SHA which deleted 7 past commits

Tags: git, github

I used this command `git push -f https://github.com/userid/reponame.git <commit-sha>:<branch-name>` for pushing commits on remote. But, that deleted 7 previous commits of that branch.

Is there any way to restore those commits or undo this change? Thanks.

Edit: The SHA I used was of a merged commit, and I have not fetched that branch before at which I pushed.

Comment: Checkout that branch, and force push again?

Comment: I have updated the question - have not fetched the branch and just pushed a commit of another branch using SHA.

Comment: The only way that commits can be lost on a push is if you force push (which you did, using the `-f` argument). Force pushing is dangerous. Did you do that deliberately? It's probably a good idea to avoid force pushing in your day to day activity. Only use it when you know you need to.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish by running that command?

Comment: Agreed with you @Chris! I was trying to push a commit by its SHA. That commit was already merged in another branch, so after running the above command some top of branch commits gone so that both branches could become even. I have chosen wrong command for the job.

Comment: You wanted to add the commit identified by the SHA on top of that branch?

Comment: yes, I should have merged from branch.

Comment: You just learned the hard way that you should never use '-f'/--force option but should always use '--force-with-lease'. That way you will most of the time avoid the problem and if it happens, always will be able to repair your mistake using the 'reflog'

Answer (score 1):

If the *server to which you pushed* does not have reflogs enabled—and this is the usual default for most servers—then those commits are *gone from the server*, at least as far as Git itself is involved.  (The server may have backups, and those backups may have the commits in some form, but whether this is so and how to restore them is beyond the scope of this community :-) —you'd want [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).)

Note that if you can log in to the server, you can check to see if by luck the server has reflogs, or `git gc` has not actually deleted the commits yet.  Both of these are somewhat unlikely, but not impossible (especially in newer Git versions that use the "quarantine area" for incoming commits, which was done in part to avoid the need to immediately run `git gc` after each received upload).

If you have not `git fetch`ed those commits into *your own* repository, so that they never existed in your own repository, then those commits continue not to exist in your own repository.  They cannot be recovered from a place in which they never existed.

That leaves only one more place to look, although it's a big place: *every other computer that has ever done a `git fetch` from the server.*  You may get lucky and find that one of *these* machines has the commits.  If so, you can retrieve the commits from that machine.

If not, the commits are gone forever.

Comment: As that repo was an open source project with the good number of contributors, I am hoping the commits would be restored by moderators and admin. Although thanks for helping.

Comment: I still have SHA's of those commits. Is there any way i can merge them using SHA ?

Comment: If you have the hashes as valid hashes, then you *do* have those commits in your repository.  You can tell because `git rev-parse <short-hash>` will produce the full hash.  If you don't have them in your repository, having the short hash, or even the full hash, is no help: the hash is merely the *key* of the key-value pair, and the *value* is the content of the commit.

Comment: Actually, those commits are generated by someone else, I got hash from the Github Activity. The hash is valid as I can see the change. The hash is not showing any branch associated with it.

Comment: If you're looking at the hash *via* GitHub, that means that GitHub itself *does* have the commit. Whether *you* can get the commit *from* GitHub, in order to convince GitHub to set the branch name back to the hash ID, is another question entirely. Note that GitHub was one of the primary movers behind the new quarantine code—they have all kinds of useful optimizations that they don't directly expose, so they have methods ordinary users cannot necessarily access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ git reflog origin/branch-name
```

It will print any move of origin/branch-name and get the corresponding commit number.

Using:

```
$ git show commit-number
```

You can retrieve the last lost commit and then checkout it to recreate a new branch.

Comment: I have not fetched the branch and just pushed a commit of another branch using SHA so i guess reflog wouldn't work.

Comment: @GauravSachdeva You configure remote.origin.fetch to not fetch all remote branches?

Comment: So I think you have all remote branches. Did you try with reflog?

Comment: Reflog is not beneficial as my branch was outdated.